# Display javascript variable in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Hi I have the following which I would like the total to be displayed on a confirmation page but I am unable to achieve this.

```
var totalPrice = $(price).val() * $(payslips-required).val();
$(total).val(totalPrice);
```

price and payslips-required are taken from a form. The price is multiplied by the the number of payslips-required to gain the total.

I have tried document write to display but I am not able to do this in the contact form 7 plugin on wordpress it causes the info on the confirmation page to disappear.

I would like it to display the total within  or  tags if possible.

```
<div id="total">Total<span id="totalprice"></span></div>
```

I want it to display the total in the span tag

Any help would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE

```
<div id="confirm"><h2 id="myAnchor">Please verify order confirmation and proceed</h2>   <br /> <div id="total">Total<span id="totalprice"></span></div></br />   <label>Title:</label>   [title]<br />   <label>Marital Status:</label>   [marital-status]<br />   <label>First Name:</label>   [first-name]<br />   <label>Middle Name:</label>   [middle-names]<br />   <label>Last Name:</label>   [last-name]<br />   <label>Home Address:</label>   [home-address]<br />   <label>Postcode:</label>   [postcode]<br />   <label>Email:</label>   [email]<br />   <label>Contact Number:</label>   [contact-number]<br />   <label>Delivery Address:</label>   [delivery-address]<br />   <label>Postcode:</label>   [delivery-postcode]<br />   <label>Gross Annual Salary:</label>   [annual-salary]<br />   <label>Monthly NET Pay:</label>   [monthly-netpay]<br />   <label>Method of Pay:</label>   [payment-method]<br />   <label>Payslips Required:</label>   [payslips-required] £[price]<br /> <label>Years Required:</label> [years-required]<br />   <label>Day of the month you are paid:</label>   [dayof-pay] <br />   <label>Month Required:</label>   [months-required]<br />   <label>Which Payslip is required:</label>   [payslip-chosen]<br />   <label>Taxcode:</label>   [taxcode]<br />   <label>National Insuarance Number :</label>   [nh1] [nh2] [nh3] [nh4] [nh5]<br />   <label>Date of Starting job:</label>   [date-of-starting-job]<br />   <label>Payslip ref no:</label>   [payslip-ref-no]<br />   <label>Company Name:</label>   [company-name]<br />          <a href="#"  class="submit">Continue to Payment</a> <a href="javascript:fadeIn('hideme');" class="edit">Cancel/ Redo</a></div>
```

Comment: can you show us some code ?

Comment: Would that not be $("#total").val(totalPrice); and same for $("#price")...

Comment: Yes similar for `$("#price").val() * $("#payslips-required").val()` i guess.

Comment: And are they classes or IDs? Please show some code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, You need to do as like

```
$('form.wpcf7-form.payment-form').submit(function() {

    var price = isNaN(parseFloat($("#price").val())) ? 0.0 : parseFloat($("#price").val())
    var payslips = isNaN(parseFloat($("#payslips-required").val())) ? 0.0 : parseFloat($("#payslips-required").val())
    var totalPrice = price * payslips;
    $("#totalprice").val(totalPrice);

});
```

And secondly if you just need javascript way, use like this

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function() {

    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    var payslips = document.getElementById("payslips-required").value;
    price = isNaN(parseFloat(price)) ? 0.0 : parseFloat(price);
    payslips = isNaN(parseFloat(payslips)) ? 0.0 : parseFloat(payslips);
    var totalPrice = price * payslips;
    document.getElementById("totalprice").value = totalPrice;

}
```

**UPDATE**

Add the below fields after the html you have show, which prints the value.

```
<input type="hidden" id="my-price" value="[price]" />
<input type="hidden" id="my-payslips-required" value="[payslips-required]" />
```

Then call the script to run,

so finally, your code will be,

```
<script>
 function CalculateTotal() {
    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    var payslips = document.getElementById("payslips-required").value;
    price = isNaN(parseFloat(price)) ? 0.0 : parseFloat(price);
    payslips = isNaN(parseFloat(payslips)) ? 0.0 : parseFloat(payslips);
    var totalPrice = price * payslips;
    document.getElementById("totalprice").value = totalPrice;
 }
</script>
```

Try the above.

Comment: Price and payslips-required are from a form you can see it here http://payslips4u.co.uk/order-monthly-payslips/ How would I go about displaying the code you provided into the div/span tags?

Comment: Updated the code. Just i need to know when did you like the code to be run. Do you want this to run when you submit the form, on on change event you want ?

Comment: Once the form is submitted

Comment: Hi I have tried both examples and both do not show the total price as it should. If you would like to see try fill the form and submitting to see for yourself. btw appreciate the help

Comment: Got you, when you are submitting the form, you form is getting cleared. Allow me some time to figure out the way u need to handle it.

Comment: I am able to recall the information submitted from the form using short code on contact form 7 (wordpress plugin) for example [price] and [payslips-required]. Oh and the form uses ajax so doesn't leave the page.

Comment: where you have "<print your value over here>" I place [price] and [payslips-required] as that is how I print/show the form content but it does not work.

Comment: Ok making it simple, can you show the whole code you use to print the values to html page ?

Comment: Can u check adding my current code after your code that you added now ?

Comment: You have added it at the wrong place. Try now. You need to just call the `CalculateTotal()` once the data are send to the server and you have printed the values to html page.

Comment: sorry I'm not great with all this how do i call CalculateTotal() ?

Comment: Would it be easier to add the total in after the user selects the number of payslips and have it display both price and total rather then after?

Comment: Yes it would be easy if you make to show the total once the user selects the payslips.

Comment: How would I modify the code you provided to do this? Thanks for all the help I really do appreciate all this!

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused if you're having trouble calculating the totalPrice, or if you're just new to JavaScript and don't know how to input the value in the span. If it's the latter, it's a pretty simple solution...

```
document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = totalPrice;
```